# MySQL - Trying sum() of two column after two group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, multiple-columns

Recently I've been trying to group_by 2 column and then sum() them together. I found an answer and I want to share it with you in a specific situation. Feel free to post another solution.

This is my database's table:

```
CREATE TABLE vote
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    prefix VARCHAR(20),
    isSchool TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    schoolName VARCHAR(100),
    choix1 INT(30) NOT NULL,
    choix2 INT(30) NOT NULL,
    dateVote INT(50) NOT NULL,
    choix1score DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    choix2score DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id ON vote (id)
```

And this is the query for my solution:

```
SELECT 
    query.choix as choix, SUM(query.result) as result
FROM
    (SELECT 
         choix2 as choix, SUM(choix2score) AS result 
     FROM 
         vote
     GROUP BY 
         choix2

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         choix1, SUM(choix1score) AS result 
     FROM 
         vote
     GROUP BY 
         choix1) AS query
GROUP BY 
    choix
ORDER BY 
    result DESC
```

So what is this? It's the database for an voting app. The user can vote for two of his favorite movie and depending on if the user have an account on my site or is annonymous, the vote score will be 2 and 1, or 0.5 and 0.25. I need ti get the total of point by grouping all point from choice1, grouping all point from choice2, and then sum them together. So, if you are like me and you look for a quick solution, this query work pretty well. But, is there a better solution?

Thanks you, Devoplex.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions looking for style improvements on working code belong on CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So you query works ok as is now?

Comment: Maybe you should normalize your schema so you don't have multiple columns. Add another table `choix` with columns `voter_id, choix_num, choix, choix_score`

Comment: @Barmar: While this may be a good idea, I don't think this would be called normalization.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm sorry for the inconveniant, and thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather union the two tables first and aggregate then:

```
select choix, sum(choixscore) as result
from
(
  select choix1 as choix, choix1score as choixscore from vote
  union all
  select choix2 as choix, choix2score as choixscore from vote
) all_scores
group by choix
order by result desc;
```

Comment: I don't like this one because won't use any index on the union result. But depends on how much the rows are reduce from the `group by`'s

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: I do hope the DBMS doesn't muddle its way through indexes when it needs to read the *whole table!* Using an index would most certainly make this run much slower than simply reading the table sequentially.

Comment: You are right. A full scan is need it anyway. I tough the `group by -  sum` would benefit for an index but as  you point out will probably be slower

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: You are right, thanks you for you reply.